# How to freeze first 2 cols of a table while scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

i have table inside of a div. When ever the div is scrolling the first two columns of the table has to be freeze(always visible). How to do this with jquery.

here is the code where i need the help.

```
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 1000px;">
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 200px; background-color:Aqua;">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px; background-color:Aqua;">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
        <td style="width: 200px">
            asd;alskd;laksd;lka
        </td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<td style="width: 200px; background-color:Aqua; position:fixed;">
    asd;alskd;laksd;lka
</td>
<td style="width: 200px; background-color:Aqua;position:fixed;">
    asd;alskd;laksd;lka
</td>
```

Comment: you can add `left: **px;` or something like that? I'm not a code monkey you know ;-)

Comment: Not only alignment the second column is going back to first column.

Comment: thanks for ur reply i am poor in css, jquery my actual requirement is here [see this](http://jsfiddle.net/243RE/1/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/243RE/2/ not sure what behaviour you exactly expect but, I think you figure out with this code

Comment: i am looking to freeze the columns in [flex grid](http://flexigrid.info/) i posted in this forum i did't got any reply so i changed the question like this any how u did ur best i am marking ur answer. Thanq

Answer (score -1):

I have invented my Own way, no need of Jquery or other tools, just plain HTML and CSS
I achive the same effect but very basic, will improve it soon.
TRY this

**** Adjust the columns width according to your requirements.

```
      <div id=main-table>
      <table name=myTable1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding=0 border=1 width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse">

              <thead>
                <tr class="header">
                <th class="labels">&nbsp;</th>
                <th valign=top width="23" class="labels">&nbsp;</th>
                <th valign=top width="78" class="labels">
                Followup Date</th>
                <th valign=top width="77" class="labels">
                First Name</th>
                <th valign=top width="91" class="labels">
                Last Name</th>
                <th valign=top width="126" class="labels">
                Email</th>
                <th valign=top width="91" class="labels">
                Phone1</th>
                <th valign=top width="91" class="labels">
                Phhne2</th>
                <th valign=top width="90" class="labels">
                Industry</th>
                <th valign="top" class="labels"  width=89>
                Company</th>
                <th valign="top" class="labels" width=92>City</th>
                <th valign="top" class="labels" width=42>State</th>
                <th valign=top width="42" class="labels">
                Zip</th>
                <th valign=top width="182" class="labels">
                Website</th>
            </tr>
               </thead>
      </table>
      <div id="table-contents">
        <table id="myTable1" name=myTable1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding=0 border=1 style="border-collapse: collapse">

          <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B3" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="78" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="77" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="91" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="126" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="91" class="first_row"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="91" class="first_row"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="90" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" name="autocompleteindustry" id="autocompleteindustry" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td width="89" class="first_row"><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td width="92" class="first_row">
                <input name=autocomplete id=autocomplete  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td width="42" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" name="autocompletest" id="autocompletest" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="42" class="first_row">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108" class="first_row"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

              <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B4" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst" id="autocomplete_GGst" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B5" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst" id="autocomplete_GGst" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B6" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst" id="autocomplete_GGst" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B7" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst" id="autocomplete_GGst" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B8" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst" id="autocomplete_GGst" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B9" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst" id="autocomplete_GGst" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B10" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst_GG" id="autocomplete_GGst_GG" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                <input type="checkbox" name="C1" value="ON"></td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                <input type="button" value="..." name="B11" style="font-size: 8pt;height:22px;width:19px"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" id="datepicker_GG"  size="8" name="txtdt"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                <input type="text" name="T1" size="8"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="T2" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                <input type="text" name="T3" size="15"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T4" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75"><input type="text" name="T5" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" id="autocomplete_GGindustry_GG" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="T6" size="10"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td>
                <input name=autocomplete_GG id=autocomplete_GG  size="10"  class="row-first" value="Atlanta"></td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="autocomplete_GGst_GG" id="autocomplete_GGst_GG" size="3"  class="row-first" value="GA"></td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                <input type="text" name="T7" size="3"  class="row-first"></td>
                <td valign=top width="108"><input type="text" name="T8" size="20"  class="row-first"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign=top width="20">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="23">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="61">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="110">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="75">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="33">
                &nbsp;</td>
                <td valign=top width="108">
                &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
              </tbody>
        </table>
          </div>
          </div>

<style>
input.row-first{
font-family:verdana;height:22px;background:#ffff11;border:0px;padding:0;margin:0;
}
.labels{
font-family:arial;font-size:12px;font-   weight:bold;color:#ffffff;background:#d344dd;height:30px;
}
#main-table{
width: 1150px;
}
#table-contents{
overflow: scroll; height:400px; width:1150px;
}

</style>
```

Soon going to add it on http://www.eddmpostcardprinting.com